# Aligning Text with Container/Icon in Row

Tags: flutter, dart

My Issue: Aligning `Text` with `Container` / `Icon` in `Row`

Current Output: (I want to align this blue line with text horizontally center)
[image: I want to align this line with text horizontally center]

Expected Output: (Red horizontal line for a guideline)
[image: Expected Output]

My current code:

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Text(
      'Unit Details',
      style: textTheme.bodyLarge,
    ),
    kHorizontalSpaceS,
    Container(
      height: 4,
      width: 42,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Pallete.brandColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I have less knowledge about `Text` baseline, but I tried with `CrossAxisAlignment.baseline` but it's not working.

How can I horizontally align this blue `Container` with the text?

I faced a similar issue with aligning `Icon` and `Text` in `Row`.

Comment: It's already centred with the base widget, Your text widget contains Capital & small letter which is why the container/Icon does not look in the centre if you want to test Icon is already centred on not please Capitalize your text. You need to just remove container height.

Comment: See this output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dDLO1Z3bBuvWO5xeTnvPE8aT2lwlKVJ3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **mainAxisAlignment** since it is a row.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem can be in TextStyle, maybe your text style height is greater than one, cause I run your code in my side with TextStyle(fontSize:30), and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Can you wrap your code with Container and give needful height.

```
       Container(
        height: 20,
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [],
        ),
```